# What language is used to describe an Abstract Syntax Tree in ESTree?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

I am referring the ESTree documentation for ECMAScript 2015 [here](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es2015.md).

For instance, it uses the following syntax:

```
extend interface Program {
    sourceType: "script" | "module";
    body: [ Statement | ModuleDeclaration ];
}

interface ForOfStatement <: ForInStatement {
    type: "ForOfStatement";
}
```

What language is this representation of the AST? Where can we read about the specification used to describe an AST or explanation of the custom format used?

Comment: From [the README](https://github.com/estree/estree#ast-descriptor-syntax): "*The spec uses a custom syntax to describe its structures.*". Also see issues [133](https://github.com/estree/estree/issues/133) and [156](https://github.com/estree/estree/pull/156)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also pointed out by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), the [README](https://github.com/estree/estree#ast-descriptor-syntax) states

> The spec uses a custom syntax to describe its structures.

The core model is described in [es5.md](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md) and contains most of the basics required to understand the extensions described in higher specifications (ES2015+).